# vue codemirror cannot load import on startup

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to load the code-mirror in a component.

```
import 'codemirror-cdn';
import {codemirror} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-codemirror@4.0.6/dist/vue-codemirror.min.js';
```

loading it via above statements but getting error

```
vue-router.js:1927 SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-codemirror@4.0.6/dist/vue-codemirror.min.js' does not provide an export named 'codemirror'
```

Answer (score 0):

If using the CDN, this should be included in the `template` tag:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-codemirror@4.0.6/dist/vue-codemirror.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You don’t use import if using the tag. Try removing the braces when using import.